# Invalid use of non-static data member when declaring pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

So I understand there are tons of other questions just like this, but I've been searching for about 2h and haven't found one that has worked for me yet. In this code, I'm trying to create a simple stack using a class template; however, I keep getting the error: Invalid use of non-static data members when attempting to declare a pointer to my array (T*Arr). I get the same error when initializing my int ArrTop, but not my int ArrSize? Finally, I also get the errors cannot call member function without object when I attempt to call Top() and Empty() from within the .cpp file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
const int DEFAULTSIZE=100;


template <class T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack();                    // Default Constructor, stack is size 100.
    Stack(const int size);      // Constructor, creates stack of size "size"
    Stack(const Stack<T> & item);// Copy constructor
    bool Full();                // Return true if the stack is full
    bool Empty();               // Return true if the stack is empty
    int Size();                 // Return the size of the stack
    T Top();                    // Returns the top element, does not pop it.
    bool Push (const T item);   // Put an item on the stack.
    bool Pop();                 // Pop an item off and display to std out
   friend ostream &operator <<(ostream & os, Stack<T> &s)
   {
        if(Empty())
                {
                cout<<"Stack underflow!";
                }
        else
                {
                cout<<"Element: "<<Top()<<"has been removed"<<endl;
                Arr[ArrTop--];
                }
   }

private:
     T *Arr;                        // The "stack"
     int ArrSize;                  // The number of elements the stack can hold
     int ArrTop;                  // Points to the first empty node
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
Arr = new T[DEFAULTSIZE];
ArrSize = DEFAULTSIZE;
ArrTop = -1;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const int size)
{
Arr = new T[size];
ArrSize=size;
ArrTop = -1;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::Empty()
{
if(ArrTop==-1)
        return true;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
int Stack<T>::Size()
{
return ArrTop+1;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::Full()
{
if(Size()==ArrSize)
        return true;

}
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::Pop()
{
if(Empty())
        {
        cout<<"Stack underflow!";
        return false;
        }
cout<<"Element: "<<Top()<<"has been removed"<<endl;
Arr[ArrTop--];
return true;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::Top()
{
if(!Empty())
        {
        return Arr[ArrTop];
        }
else
        {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::Push(const T item)
{
if(Full())
        {
        cout<<"Stack overflow!";
        return false;
        }
else
        {
        cout<<"Element: "<<item<<"has been inserted!"<<endl;
        Arr[ArrTop++]=item;
        }
}
```

Then there are the errors I'm getting:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
stack.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Stack<T>&)’:
stack.cpp:45:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Stack<T>::Arr’
      T *Arr;              // The "stack"
         ^
stack.cpp:40:3: error: from this location
   Arr[ArrTop--];
   ^
stack.cpp:47:10: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Stack<T>::ArrTop’
      int ArrTop;                  // Points to the first empty node
          ^
stack.cpp:40:7: error: from this location
   Arr[ArrTop--];
       ^
stack.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Stack<char>&)’:
main.cpp:29:16:   required from here
stack.cpp:33:11: error: cannot call member function ‘bool Stack<T>::Empty() [with T = char]’ without object
  if(Empty())
           ^
stack.cpp:39:26: error: cannot call member function ‘T Stack<T>::Top() [with T = char]’ without object
   cout<<"Element: "<<Top()<<"has been removed"<<endl;
                          ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Again, thank you guys so much, you're the best!

Comment: Tip: [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) already exists. No need to roll your own.

Comment: I know this is for an assignment!

Comment: not the problem but the output operator should take a `const` reference

Comment: Your `operator<<` function is semantically wrong. It's the stream output operator, it should print the contents of the stack to the stream `os`. And it's not a "pop" operator.

Comment: is it possible that you actually want to implement a `Stack::operator<<` that pops an element from the stack?

Comment: in other words: How do you plan to use that operator?

Comment: The operator is supposed to act as a pop function then send out whatever it poped to the stream I guess. My professor wrote that, and to be frank, I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator<<` function isn't a member function, it doesn't have the functions `Empty` or `Top`, or the variables `Arr` or `ArrTop` declared. You need to use the functions and variables from the `s` object.

Like for example

```
if (s.Empty()) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: note that OP is not using the stream in the operator. This may silence the error, but it will still not be a proper output operator

Comment: How do I do a proper output operator? Also what exactly is a output operator?